Appium TouchAction Hold Without Duration Alternative
I currently have 2 methods to handle touch actions of hold and release
       public static void HoldLongPressByCoordinates(int x, int y, int waitTime = 3)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTime));
            TouchAction touchActionHold = new TouchAction(_driver);
            touchActionHold.LongPress(x, y).Perform();
        }

        public static void ReleaseLongPressByCoordinates()
        {
            touchAction.Release().Perform();
        }

TouchActions are obviously deprecated with newer versions.
From what i saw I can use it this way
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
var scriptArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "x", x },
        { "y", y },
        { "duration", 30000 } // Duration in milliseconds
    };
js.ExecuteScript("mobile: longClickGesture", scriptArgs);


But, I cant seem to find a way to hold without a duration so i could perform other actions while hold is still active.
Is there any other way to make it work like i had with the touch actions?
